# RSpec Error in Cucumber Test

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber

I am new to Ruby and Cucumber and am working through some exercises in *The Cucumber Book*. I am trying to implement a feature so the user may not over withdraw from an atm. I'm receiving this error on the 3rd step definition: `expected: 0 got: 20 (using ==) (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)` . Here is my code:

Feature:

```
Feature: Prevent users from going overdrawn

 Scenario: User tries to withdraw more than their balance

  Given I have credited $100 in my account
  When I withdraw $200
  Then $0 should be dispensed
  And I should be told that I have insufficient funds in my account
```

Step Definitions:

```
Given /^I have credited (#{CAPTURE_CASH_AMOUNT}) in my account$/ do |amount|
  my_account.credit(amount)
end

When /^I withdraw (#{CAPTURE_CASH_AMOUNT})$/ do |amount|
  teller.withdraw_from(my_account, amount)
end

Then /^(#{CAPTURE_CASH_AMOUNT}) should be dispensed$/ do |amount|
  cash_slot.contents.should == amount
end

Then /^the balance of my account should be (#{CAPTURE_CASH_AMOUNT})$/ do |amount|
  my_account.balance.should eq(amount),
    "Expected Then balance to be #{amount} but it was #{my_account.balance}"
end
```

Support module:

```
module KnowsTheUserInterface
  class UserInterface
    include Capybara::DSL

    def withdraw_from(account, amount)
      Sinatra::Application.account = account
      visit '/'
      choose('amount-20')
      click_button('Withdraw')
    end
  end

  def my_account
    @my_account ||= Account.new
  end

  def cash_slot
    Sinatra::Application.cash_slot
  end

  def teller
    @teller ||= UserInterface.new
  end
end

World(KnowsTheUserInterface)
```

And my ruby file from my lib folder:

```
class Account
  def balance
    @balance
  end

  def credit(amount)
    @balance = amount
  end

  def debit(amount)
    @balance -= amount
  end
end


class CashSlot
  def contents
    @contents or raise("I'm empty!")
  end

  def dispense(amount)
    @contents = amount
  end
end


class Teller
  def initialize(cash_slot)
    @cash_slot = cash_slot
  end

  def withdraw_from(account, amount)
    account.debit(amount)
    @cash_slot.dispense(amount)
  end

end

require 'sinatra'
get '/' do
  %{
    <html>
      <body>
        <form action="/withdraw" method="post">
          <label for="amount">Choose amount here:</label>

          <input type="radio" value="20" name="amount" id="amount-20">$20</input>
          <input type="radio" value="40" name="amount" id="amount-40">$40</input>
          <input type="radio" value="60" name="amount" id="amount-60">$60</input>
          <input type="radio" value="100" name="amount" id="amount-100">$100</input>
          <input type="submit" value="Withdraw"></input >


        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
  }
end


set :cash_slot, CashSlot.new
set :account do
  fail 'account has not been set'
end
post '/withdraw' do
  teller = Teller.new(settings.cash_slot)
  teller.withdraw_from(settings.account, params[:amount].to_i)
end
```

I know I've got some disconnect with how the step definitions are talking to each other. I've been unable to find any reference online.

Comment: You're always withdrawing the same amount ($20)

Comment: Yes indeed, thank you for catching that. I was able to get that step to pass.